# Breaking equation with LuaLaTeX

Tags: luatex, line-breaking, breqn, luacode, directlua

The following code works as expected. It breaks mathematics expression in multi-lines.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{breqn}
\begin{document}
\begin{dmath*}
 f(1.02) + f (1.06) + f (1.1) + f (1.14) + f (1.18) + f (1.22) + f (1.26) + f (1.3) + f (1.34) + f (1.38) + f (1.42) + f (1)
\end{dmath*}
\end{document}
```

However the following does not work. It does not break mathematics expression in multi-lines.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luacode,breqn}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\luaTest}{{%
\directlua{%
local mystr = [[
f(1.02) + f (1.06) + f (1.1) + f (1.14) + f (1.18) + f (1.22) + f (1.26) + f (1.3) + f (1.34) + f (1.38) + f (1.42) + f (1)
]]
tex.print(tostring(mystr))
}%
}%
}%
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{dmath*}
\luaTest
\end{dmath*}
\end{document}
```

What is the issue? How can it be solved?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is not related to the Lua, a brace group prevents breaking

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{breqn}
\begin{document}
\begin{dmath*}
 {f(1.02) + f (1.06) + f (1.1) + f (1.14) + f (1.18) + f (1.22) + f (1.26) + f (1.3) + f (1.34) + f (1.38) + f (1.42) + f (1)}
\end{dmath*}
\end{document}
```

Removing the group allows breaking

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luacode,breqn}

\newcommand{\luaTest}{%
\directlua{%
local mystr = [[
f(1.02) + f (1.06) + f (1.1) + f (1.14) + f (1.18) + f (1.22) + f (1.26) + f (1.3) + f (1.34) + f (1.38) + f (1.42) + f (1)
]]%
tex.print(tostring(mystr))%
}%
}%

\begin{document}
\begin{dmath*}
\luaTest
\end{dmath*}
\end{document}
```

If (for reasons not shown) you really need a group you could use `\begingroup`

```
\newcommand{\luaTest}{\begingroup
\directlua{%
local mystr = [[
f(1.02) + f (1.06) + f (1.1) + f (1.14) + f (1.18) + f (1.22) + f (1.26) + f (1.3) + f (1.34) + f (1.38) + f (1.42) + f (1)
]]%
tex.print(tostring(mystr))%
}%
\endgroup}%
```